# How to cancel AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to cancel my request when user press back or close Dialog.but it execute at least one time even i cancel it. sendPost is use to upload pictures .I want when user cancel Dialog then request should not execute

```
private class sendd extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String success, mess, response, user;
    Button next;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public sendd(Context ctx) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FilenewReport.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Updating ");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
                // stick to contract.
                running = false;
                // cancel(true);
                sends.cancel(true);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        sends.cancel(true);
        running = false;

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (running) {

            try {
                sendPost(file_url, imagepath);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // }
            }
            // if (check == false || isCancelled()) {
            // break;
            // }
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void notUsed) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually if the communication for uploading to server is initiated then  cancelling task will stop the further execution of task but will not stop the initiated communication, Even if you reset the connections then too what have been already sent will be written on server side, ya but as you have cancelled you won't be able to receive the response  from server.

Comment: i am getting response  also

Comment: ok so it might be happening in a fraction.

Comment: any way i can stop it

Comment: this is good way ? pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
     // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
     // stick to contract.
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
      }
     });
    }
   });

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to cancel the request in doInBackground:

```
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

onPostExecute method will not execute in this case.

Comment: Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       try {
        
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        Log.i("close", "close");
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     });
     thread.start();

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Add to the start of the while loop in your doInBackground:

```
if (isCancelled()) {
    return null;
}
```

`onPostExecute` won't be executed after this, only `onCancelled`.

Comment: this is good way ? pDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
     // actually could set running = false; right here, but I'll
     // stick to contract.
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
      }
     });
    }
   });